# Error when trying to create LMDB files

Tags: caffe

I am trying to work on my own dataset,in order to do so,i have to create a LMDB file,i had used this script to create the LMDB file of a different dataset,it worked fine then now it just throws an error.
This is the script.

```
CAFFE_ROOT=/home/decentmakeover/caffe
OUTPUT=/home/decentmakeover/invasive_species
LABEL_TEXT_ROOT=/home/decentmakeover/invasive_species
TRAIN_DATA_ROOT=/home/decentmakeover/invasive_species/train/
VAL_DATA_ROOT=/home/decentmakeover/invasive_species/train/

# Set RESIZE=true to resize the images to 256x256. Leave as false if 
images have
# already been resized using another tool.
#RESIZE=false
RESIZE=true
if $RESIZE; then
  RESIZE_HEIGHT=256
  RESIZE_WIDTH=256
else
  RESIZE_HEIGHT=0
  RESIZE_WIDTH=0
fi

echo "Creating train lmdb..."

TOOLS=$CAFFE_ROOT/build/tools

GLOG_logtostderr=1 $TOOLS/convert_imageset \
    --resize_height=$RESIZE_HEIGHT \
    --resize_width=$RESIZE_WIDTH \
    --shuffle \
    $TRAIN_DATA_ROOT \
    $LABEL_TEXT_ROOT/train.txt \
    $OUTPUT/invasive_species_train_lmdb

echo "Creating val lmdb..."

GLOG_logtostderr=1 $TOOLS/convert_imageset \
    --resize_height=$RESIZE_HEIGHT \
    --resize_width=$RESIZE_WIDTH \
    --shuffle \
    $VAL_DATA_ROOT \
    $LABEL_TEXT_ROOT/val.txt \
    $OUTPUT/invasive_species_val_lmdb

echo "Compute image mean..."

$TOOLS/compute_image_mean $OUTPUT/invasive_species_train_lmdb \
  $OUTPUT/invasive_species_mean.binaryproto

echo "Done."
```

and this is the Error:
 [The Error Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niBh1.png)

Any suggestion as to how to fix this would help

Answer (score 1):

The directory where the LMDB is being created must exist beforehand.

Ensure that the empty directories `invasive_species_train_lmdb` and `invasive_species_val_lmdb` are created in the path `OUTPUT` before you run this script.